# Cassandra collection tombstones

Tags: collections, cassandra

I have created a table with a collection. Inserted a record and took sstabledump of it and seeing there is range tombstone for it in the sstable. Does this tombstone ever get removed? Also when I run sstablemetadata on the only sstable, it shows "Estimated droppable tombstones" as 0.5", Similarly it shows one record with epoch time as insert time for - "Estimated tombstone drop times: 1548384720:         1". Does it mean that when I do sstablemetadata on a table having collections, the estimated droppable tombstone ratio and drop times values are not true and dependable values due to collection/list range tombstones?

```
CREATE TABLE ks.nmtest (
    reservation_id text,
    order_id text,
    c1 int,
    order_details map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (reservation_id, order_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (order_id ASC)

user@cqlsh:ks> insert into nmtest (reservation_id , order_id , c1, order_details ) values('3','3',3,{'key':'value'});
user@cqlsh:ks> select * from nmtest ;
 reservation_id | order_id | c1 | order_details
----------------+----------+----+------------------
              3 |        3 |  3 | {'key': 'value'}
(1 rows)

[root@localhost nmtest-e1302500201d11e983bb693c02c04c62]# sstabledump mc-5-big-Data.db 
WARN  02:52:19,596 memtable_cleanup_threshold has been deprecated and should be removed from cassandra.yaml
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "3" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 41,
        "clustering" : [ "3" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-01-25T02:51:13.574409Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "c1", "value" : 3 },
          { "name" : "order_details", "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2019-01-25T02:51:13.574408Z", "local_delete_time" : "2019-01-25T02:51:13Z" } },
          { "name" : "order_details", "path" : [ "key" ], "value" : "value" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

SSTable: /data/data/ks/nmtest-e1302500201d11e983bb693c02c04c62/mc-5-big
Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
Bloom Filter FP chance: 0.010000
Minimum timestamp: 1548384673574408
Maximum timestamp: 1548384673574409
SSTable min local deletion time: 1548384673
SSTable max local deletion time: 2147483647
Compressor: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor
Compression ratio: 1.0714285714285714
TTL min: 0
TTL max: 0
First token: -155496620801056360 (key=3)
Last token: -155496620801056360 (key=3)
minClustringValues: [3]
maxClustringValues: [3]
Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.5
SSTable Level: 0
Repaired at: 0
Replay positions covered: {CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1548382769966, position=6243201)=CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1548382769966, position=6433666)}
totalColumnsSet: 2
totalRows: 1
Estimated tombstone drop times:
1548384720:         1
```

Another quuestion was on the nodetool tablestats output - what does slice refer to in cassandra?

```
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Comment: Does tombstone_threshold depend on the sstablemetadata threshold value? If so then for tables having collections, this is not a true threshold right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sstablemetadata does not have the information about your table that is not held within the sstable as it is not guaranteed to be run on system that has Cassandra running, and even if it was its very complex to be able to know how to pull the schema information from it.

Since the `gc_grace_seconds` is a table parameter and not in the metadata it defaults to assuming a `0` gc grace so the droppable times listed in that histogram will be more a histogram of the tombstone creation times by default. If you know your gc grace you can add it as a `-g` parameter to your sstablemetadata call. like:

```
sstablemetadata -g 864000 mc-5-big-Data.db
```

see http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/sstable/sstablemetadata.html for information on the tools output.

With collections it's just normal range tombstone with all that it entails. They are used to prevent the requirement of a read-before-write when overwriting the value of a multicell collection.

Comment: For some reason I see the same values with and w/o gc_grace_seconds. ```[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx nmtest-e1302500201d11e983bb693c02c04c62]# sstablemetadata mc-11-big-Data.db | grep "Estimated tombstone drop times" -A3
Estimated tombstone drop times:
1548577440:         1
Count               Row Size        Cell Count
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx nmtest-e1302500201d11e983bb693c02c04c62]# sstablemetadata  --gc_grace_seconds 86400 mc-11-big-Data.db | grep "Estimated tombstone drop times" -A4
Estimated tombstone drop times:
1548577440:         1
Count               Row Size        Cell Count```

Comment: I did major compaction and all the tombstones disappeared and now when I run the above sstablemetadata command it does not show any tombstones. Does it mean that until there are overlapping records in multiple sstables, the output from this command cannot be relied upon? Probably good for LCS tables and not for size compaction as they span multiple sstables.

Comment: Looking at it the TombstoneHistogram kept in the metadata is a direct histogram of the dates the tombstones are created. The drop times are calculated by just taking that histogram and slicing based on now+gc_grace. The output of the metadata viewer is just showing the TombstoneHistogram. If you want to know the time that the tombstones are purgable, add the 10 days or whatever your gc grace is to that output. The tool just prints whats in the file but it should be renamed to just `Estimated Tombstone times`

Comment: `Does it mean that until there are overlapping records in multiple sstables, the output from this command cannot be relied upon?` I dont know what you mean. The sstables overlapping can prevent purging of the tombstones unless both sstables are involved in the compaction - other than that it's irrelevant.